# TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter causes memory leak

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a simple application to convert REST service response to Clientdataset. App has TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse, TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter and TClientDataSet. RESTClient receives a JSON array from a web service. RESTResponseDataSetAdapter causes a memory leak when it is activated. This code generates a memory leak:

```
RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.Response:= RESTResponse1;
RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.Dataset:= ClientDataSet1;
RESTRequest1.Resource := ServiceURL;
RESTRequest1.Execute;
RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.Active:=true;
```

[image]

What is wrong here? is it a Delphi XE7 bug? Looks like some TJSONValue was never  freed.